# Swiper js is not working properly in Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I am using swiper js in my project.
It works till i render the slides of the swiper by the static code (i mean normal slides)
When i use map function to render the multiple slides it become non-responsive for the mobile phone and desktop both.

Here is the code that i am using to render the swiper:

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import Districts from "@/app/create/components/Districts";
import "swiper/css";
import Link from "next/link";

const DistrictSwiper = () => {
    return (
        <Swiper
            spaceBetween={50}
            slidesPerView={3}
            onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
            onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
        >
            {Districts.map((item, index) => (
                <SwiperSlide
                    key={index}
                    style={{ width: "auto", display: "inline-block" }}
                    className="p-1 swiper-slide"
                >
                    <Link
                        className="px-3 py-1 text-xs border rounded-full hover:bg-slate-100"
                        href=""
                    >
                        {item.name}
                    </Link>
                </SwiperSlide>
            ))}
        </Swiper>
    );
};

export default DistrictSwiper;
```

As I add the map function it start taking whole the even more then the total screen with of my mobile device.
[image: Image showing non responsiveness]
[image: Desktop device image]

Comment: Did you try making the width: 100vw; ??

Comment: Yes It works when i give it width of 100vw. But I can't use this as its in the flex i am along with the swiper I am rendering cards on the right of it

Comment: Is their any way that i could render the swiper after the completing the map function as i think i problem only get created as after rendering the swiper its starts inserting slides in it.

Comment: Do you also need the cards on the right to be displayed when you're using it on your phone? Or do you need the cards to move below the main content or something of that sort?

Comment: When using the mobile phone they get moved to the bottom and while the computer they are on the right. Still if I want to use it I can't as my padding a margins from the side are controlled by the layouts and the other parent components. So may need to refactor my whole application

Comment: Is the swiper code and the cards on the right within the same parent component? as in <ParentComponent> <SwiperComponent /> <CardsComponent /> </ParentComponent>?

Comment: Yes!  and the swiper even works fine i remove the map function I means just render the cards with the simple static code so I think their is not problem with the parent and child components.

Comment: Thanks for your support brother founded the solution as I am using the map function it adds the more slides after the swiper render in simply need to add overflow-x-auto and its done .

Comment: <div className="flex overflow-x-auto">
                    <DistrictSwiper />
                </div>

Comment: That's great! Maybe you should add the answer.

Comment: Still its not working for the mobile. But for the desktop sites its working fine